# How to I get in xpath the value of the option and not the display value?

Tags: html, xpath

Consider this example

```
<select>
<option value="http://www.test1.com"> 1 </option>
<option value="http://www.test2.com"> 2 </option>
<option value="http://www.test3.com"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

How to I get in xpath the value of the option and not the display? Meaning, I want to get the value of the option element - http://www.test1.com for example and not 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 6):

By position:

```
/select/option[1]/@value
```

By content:

```
/select/option[.=1]/@value
```

or

```
/select/option[normalize-space()='1']/@value
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the set of all values, simply use

```
/select/option/@value
```